# Swift - How to handle completion block in for-loop?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, block

I want to display multiple animation one after another. `gifArray` has list of animation. I'm looping this array in for-loop. What happening is last animation is getting displayed and finished.

How can I continue the each loop only when current loop animation gets finished ?

```
for index in 0..<gifArray.count {
   self.makeAnimation(value: index)
}

func makeAnimation(value: Int){ 
    let anotherAnimationView = LOTAnimationView(name: gifNames[value])
    animationView = anotherAnimationView
    animationView?.play(completion: { finished in
        print("completed")
    })
    self.view.addSubview(animationView!)
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but have you tried `addSubview` before performing the animation?

Comment: @TawaNicolas Yes. Its added before performing. No changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `completionHandler` to your function which you can call when the `animation` is completed:

```
func makeAnimation(value: Int, onCompletion: @escaping (LOTAnimationView) -> Void) {
    let anotherAnimationView = LOTAnimationView(name: gifNames[value])
    animationView = anotherAnimationView
    animationView?.play(completion: { finished in
        print("completed")
        onCompletion(animationView)
    })
}
```

And to use it use the following:

```
makeAnimation(value: 1000000) { (animationView) in
    self.view.addSubview(animationView!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Each loop is not displaying one by one. Still its happening the same.

Comment: @Balasubramanian, check the updated answer were you pass the animationView in the completionHandler and add it when it´s completed instead.

Comment: Nope. tried your way. I guess we are adding animationView after finishing its play.

Answer (score 0):

Inside loop couldn't able to control the loop execution. So I took out the `makeAnimation` function from for-loop. Thanks @Rashwan L for your help.

```
self.callGIFAnimation(value: self.index){ (completed) in
      if(completed) {
          self.index = self.index + 1
          if self.index < gifNames.count {
                self.makeAnimation()
          }
          else {
              return
          }
      }
}
```